# Is there a way to wait for javascript async function to get finish before before continue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I want to wait for async function getPreprocessed to run before I return data so that message will not be undefined

```
data: result.rows.map(notification => {
            var message
            const entity_type_id = notification.entityTypeId
            const preProcess = entityTypeDetails[entity_type_id].process;

            async function getPreprocessed() {
                let processedData = []
                const promise = entityTypeDetails[entity_type_id].preProcessing
                for (let index = 0; index < promise.length; index++) {
                    const element = promise[index];
                    const processed = await element.process(notification)
                    processedData.push(processed)
                }
                processedData = Object.assign({}, ...processedData.map(object => (object)))
                message = res.__(entityTypeDetails[entity_type_id].messageProp,processedData)
            }
             getPreprocessed()
            
            return {
                    message: message,
                    notification_notifiers: notification.notification_notifiers[0]
                }
            })
```

Comment: yes, `await getPreprocessed()`

Comment: @danh The `.map()` callback is not an `async` function

Comment: @andreas I awaited getPreprocessed() and added async to .map() function but when I got to the API endpoint I do not receive the data.